# Trying to download a youtube video, but getting a weird incomprehensible http error, even via tools

Tags: http, video-conversion, youtube, youtube-dl

Have been trying this video. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mBKKZN1MMBM.
Youtube-dl doesn't work. Convert.io and https://www.onlinevideoconverter.com manually also failed.
What could have gone wrong here?

EDIT

```
(base) C:\Users\vx>youtube-dl https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mBKKZN1MMBM
[youtube] mBKKZN1MMBM: Downloading webpage
[youtube] mBKKZN1MMBM: Downloading video info webpage
[youtube] mBKKZN1MMBM: Downloading MPD manifest
[download] Destination: Flask error handling - Python on the web - Learning Flask Ep. 18-mBKKZN1MMBM.mp4
[download]   0.5% of 69.84MiB at 380.54KiB/s ETA 03:07[download] Got server HTTP error: Downloaded 348996 bytes, expected 73232110 bytes. Retrying (attempt 1 of 10)...


ERROR: Did not get any data blocks
```

Comment: Well, without the error message our guess is as good as yours.

Comment: I just thought someone can try and reproduce it. But this error is not very informative to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Youtube videos are sometimes displayed in segments, and not every download program
knows how to handle this.

According to your error, I would guess that the first segment had the size of
348996 bytes, while the total size was 73232110 bytes, so the download
did not proceed to the second segment, but instead aborted.

I have used another online downloader : [y2mate.com](https://y2mate.com/),
which had no problem with it
([link](https://y2mate.com/youtube/mBKKZN1MMBM)).

Comment: Do you know if there is a way to pass some params to youtube-dl to make it handle the segments? Or some other python library that can handle that? It seems that youtube is increasingly offering such segmenting on its videos.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know of any such option for youtube-dl, and the documentation makes no mention of it. I fear you will need to find another tool.

Comment: of course I will accept it :) I just wanted to wait if anyone might know an alternative python library.

Answer (score 0):

Do this to update youtube-dl;

`$ youtube-dl -U`

... then retry the video download.

youtube-dl is updated frequently...
if a download isn't working, always first try an update.

---

Example run:

```
$ youtube-dl https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mBKKZN1MMBM
[youtube] mBKKZN1MMBM: Downloading webpage
[youtube] mBKKZN1MMBM: Downloading video info webpage
[youtube] mBKKZN1MMBM: Downloading MPD manifest
[dashsegments] Total fragments: 180
[download] Destination: Flask error handling - Python on the web - Learning Flask Ep. 18-mBKKZN1MMBM.f299.mp4
[download] 100% of 127.05MiB in 00:14
[dashsegments] Total fragments: 92
[download] Destination: Flask error handling - Python on the web - Learning Flask Ep. 18-mBKKZN1MMBM.f140.m4a
[download] 100% of 13.94MiB in 00:04
[ffmpeg] Merging formats into "Flask error handling - Python on the web - Learning Flask Ep. 18-mBKKZN1MMBM.mp4"
Deleting original file Flask error handling - Python on the web - Learning Flask Ep. 18-mBKKZN1MMBM.f299.mp4 (pass -k to keep)
Deleting original file Flask error handling - Python on the web - Learning Flask Ep. 18-mBKKZN1MMBM.f140.m4a (pass -k to keep)
```

Comment: *From what I can see the DL is working here, locally...*

Comment: Hm. I just tried it and it's the same even though I am using the version from like today. ERROR: Did not get any data blocks

Comment: Apparently there is a new version today -> `Updating to version 2019.07.16`