# How youtube-dl works?

Tags: video, youtube, youtube-dl

How can I get direct youtube video URL? I tried to do this with Chrome Network monitor. I used this video as example: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dQw4w9WgXcQ
[image]
With this way i got this URL(It will expire tomorrow):

```
https://r2---sn-bpb5oxu-vqne.googlevideo.com/videoplayback?expire=1565036255&ei=fzpIXau_FYLwyQXAk7_IAw&ip=213.231.39.107&id=o-AMYUX0_QrQNg9MVm5kZz__GshDwdFlff2L5-DeeZzaoC&itag=248&aitags=133%2C134%2C135%2C136%2C137%2C160%2C242%2C243%2C244%2C247%2C248%2C278%2C394%2C395%2C396%2C397%2C398&source=youtube&requiressl=yes&mm=31%2C29&mn=sn-bpb5oxu-vqne%2Csn-3c27sn7k&ms=au%2Crdu&mv=m&mvi=1&pl=18&nh=%2CIgpwcjAxLmticDAxKgkxMjcuMC4wLjE&gcr=ua&initcwndbps=433750&mime=video%2Fwebm&gir=yes&clen=57856215&dur=212.040&lmt=1544415215209302&mt=1565014541&fvip=13&keepalive=yes&beids=9466586&c=web&txp=5535432&sparams=expire%2Cei%2Cip%2Cid%2Caitags%2Csource%2Crequiressl%2Cgcr%2Cmime%2Cgir%2Cclen%2Cdur%2Clmt&lsparams=mm%2Cmn%2Cms%2Cmv%2Cmvi%2Cpl%2Cnh%2Cinitcwndbps&lsig=AHylml4wRAIgZVL3xFoRK47BJCnUf8Ngmdtzb06uxvo7EqoMFrRSua4CIGRoriCRXeEa_ZF2rRZN-KztSbS9l4vzkCQuD1VKpjDr&alr=yes&sig=ALgxI2wwRgIhAOzFGe22cfpqpEjyp_QIW6BacKYIICEqPT98Mj2SPHU8AiEA_leke3wKKgzJZq4tw2D8tlX30NYpFirEnmSnjDLqjLo%3D&cpn=G9F192iSCg-PzEPT&cver=html5
```

But the problem is that I can get only with built-in network monitor. I want to know how to do this programmatically? So **how services and programs like youtube-dl obtain direct video and audio URL/URI?** Can I get video URL with audio and video without using `ffmpeg` to mux it?

Comment: The team behind `youtube-dl` spends a lot of time reverse engineering Youtube and other sites and figuring that out.  You won't get a better answer than by looking at the Python code yourself and trying to understand it.

Answer (score 2):

The URL you got is a temporary one that only has meaning on your computer.
The is no such website as `https://r2---sn-bpb5oxu-vqne.googlevideo.com/`.

On the other hand, `youtube-dl` is no longer enough for YouTube videos.
YouTube has moved away from direct video play into the streaming of
segments. Some videos still use the old system, but many videos are now
becoming more of a playlist than one video file.

Usually, the image YouTube shows on the video when you move the cursor over
the timeline is that of the segment, as you can see when it doesn't change
for a minuscule movement of the cursor.

I already answered a similar question on the post
[Trying to download a youtube video, but getting a weird incomprehensible http error, even via tools](https://superuser.com/questions/1459477/trying-to-download-a-youtube-video-but-getting-a-weird-incomprehensible-http-er).

The only solution I found was to use a more recent video
downloader than `youtube-dl`, and the one I recommended was
[y2mate.com](https://y2mate.com/).

Comment: y2mate is worse than youtube-dl. y2mate.com cannot download this video - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KHut4-LtmnM but youtube-dl can.

Comment: It think that the conclusion is that YouTube has a long history and various methods of encoding. I do know that when uploading a new video, its conversion is assigned to some internal YouTube video server, but not all such servers run the same software. You might need to use a number of such utilities and website downloaders, because there doesn't seem to be one that works for all cases.

Comment: for me, youtube-dl works for all)

Comment: Lucky you, but luck doesn't last forever. To be serious: A direct YouTube URL is no longer possible, except perhaps for videos uploaded years ago.

Comment: hey guys, maybe there's a github-issue opened already in youtube-dl repo about these playlist-based videos?